# combining sentences containing "Will be"

Tags: word-usage

I trying to combine these three sentences

> 1.Soon usability will be commodity.
>
> 2.Usability will be something that user will expect
>
> 3.Usability will not be a leverage or key differentiator

I came up with this

> Soon usability will be a commodity and it will be something users will
>   expect. It will not be a leverage or key differentiator any more.

Is there any better way

Comment: do clarify further. It's not understandable.

Comment: is it clear now @MaulikV  ?

Comment: *Soon, usability will be a commodity that is something the users would expect. This is not going to be a leverage....*?

Comment: If you start with "[ usability will be a commodity ] and [ usability will be something users expect ]", then you can factor out the first three words: "usability will be〔 [ a commodity ] and [ something users expect ] 〕"

Comment: Somehow I found this use of "commodity" didn't give me an idea of contrast to the second sentence.

Comment: We do not speak of something being *a leverage*; *leverage* (noun) is a force which is exerted with a tool. You may say that usability *provides* leverage (noun) or is something which one *may* or *can* leverage (verb) in order to effect something. But the tool itself is a *lever*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative where 2 out the 3 "will be"s have been removed:

> Soon usability will be a commodity, something users will expect and not a leverage or key differentiator any more.

If this version is too long a sentence, here's an alternative:

> Soon usability will be a commodity and something users will expect. It will not be a leverage or key differentiator any more.

**EDIT**

After reading the first alternative once more, I think it reads better if "any more" is moved from the end of the sentence:

> Soon usability will be a commodity, something users will expect, and not any more a leverage or key differentiator.

**EDIT 2**

Or as suggested by @starsplusplus using `no longer`

> Soon usability will be a commodity, something users will expect, and no longer a leverage or key differentiator.

Comment: thanks for your answer but somehow I  not comfortable with your options. let me re-factor my question

Comment: Question Edited @Nico

Comment: what in particular does it feel uncomfortable? What about `Soon usability will be a commodity, a quality users will expect, and not any more a leverage or key differentiator.`?

Comment: I think "any more" sounds more natural on the end of the sentence. If you prefer the other placement, use "no longer" instead of "not any more".